Intellij Idea not recognizing files without the absolute path
I am new to Java and intellij Idea, I was following a tutorial on how to read a file in java, when I entered any type of file path, filename ( the main class and the other file were in the same directory ), path from content root, source root, it gave FileNotFoundException except using the absolute path.
I was expecting it to work only using the filename, because the main class and the other file is in the same directory. But Intellij gives FileNotFoundException
I don't have a problem with using the absolute path but if I run my project anywhere else other than my computer than it will not work. That's why I want to know the solution to this problem so i can run my project on other places too.

it's impossible to answer without more details, like how you run your code. but in general having files in same directory will not help unless it's same as program working directory

I'm 99.99% sure this is a problem around relative paths and/or IntelliJ not copying resources to the expected folder. Check this other question to find on which directory your app is running: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871051/how-to-get-the-current-working-directory-in-java

As rkosegi says, you need to know the current directory

Check the working directory setting in the run configuration. If it still doesn't work, share a sample project on GitHub.

Aah thanks @CrazyCoder, My working directory was set to the drive. I set it to the main working directory where all the code was written now it works perfectly fine without causing any problems. Thanks for your help and everyone who read this question

More often than not you're reading 'files' as resources in Java, unless they are chosen by the user:
Netbeans
Eclipse

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
