# Auto-locating .jar

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I'm writing a program that has a `JFileChooser`.

I want default location opened in it to be the folder in which (once the program is created) programs (runnable) .jar file is residing.

Is there a simple way to locate the program inside a file system, or do I have to do it manually?

Also, if there is a simple way, what will be default location while my program is still just a project (not jar)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153337/how-do-i-get-my-current-working-directory-in-java

Comment: try to use a xml/properties file that will hold the default location and load it in the filechooser during its initialisation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the executing location:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  new Test();
}

public Test() {
  JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
  File loc = new File(getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
  jfc.setCurrentDirectory(loc);
  jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
}
```

When you're in the project, the directory will be where your class files are located.  For example, project_dir/bin/.