# How to access absolute file path of Jar being executed?

Tags: java, jar, absolute-path

I know this question has been asked a lot, but none of the previous answers seem to work for me.

If I make my app an executable Jar, is there any way of telling where that Jar is located on the file system when it is executed? My app needs to know, so it can extract a folder from within it's jar (by treating it as a zip file) to a specified directory.

EDIT: Thanks to everyone who contributed, but I think this is a dead end. I'll have to try something else. Sorry for wasting everyone's time. I'll keep checking back on this question, so if anybody does crack it, please answer :D

For what it's worth, here is my test code:

```
    package jarProblem;

import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {

    public Main () {

        ClassLoader loader = Main.class.getClassLoader();

        String path = loader.getResource("jarProblem/Main.class").getPath();

        File file = new File(path);

        String pathToJar = file.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), new JLabel(pathToJar),"CurrentFolder", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        new Main();
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153337/how-do-i-get-my-current-working-directory-in-java

Comment: The accepted answer for that question displays "rsrc:./" when I add it to my test code

Comment: I just used it and it works completely fine for me. What folder is your JAR file in?

Comment: My desktop (C:/Users/CptSpike/Desktop)

Comment: How interesting. Have you tried any of the other suggestions present on that thread?

Comment: All of them. They mostly return C:/Windows/System32

Comment: What IDE are you using to export the JAR? Have you tried making it a standard JAR file instead of an Executable JAR?

Comment: Hadn't thought of that. I'm using Eclipse. It's worth noting that `URL location = Test.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();` returns something meaningful when ran from Eclipse, but after exporting as runnable Jar file, it returns "rsrc:./"

Comment: Aye, try it as a normal JAR file :)

Comment: Now it doesn't run at all :(

Answer (score 0):

```
System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

Comment: Returns "C:/Windows/System32" which is where javaw.exe is located

Comment: Your javaw is located in System32 folder? From what I know, javaw is installed, by default, in Program Files/Java/jdk<version>/bin...
Maybe your environment variables are returning this path.

Comment: I thought that was odd. My JDK is in Program Files/Java and does have a javaw.exe too. Either way, it's not pointing to my desktop :(

Comment: Take a look at your environment variables and the paths there... seems to be bad configuration

Comment: Seems to be nothing out of the ordinary to me. The C:/Windows/System32.javaw.exe isn't mentioned at all, funnily

Comment: That's because We don't put the absolute path with filename (i.e. C:/Windows/System32/javaw.exe). We put the absolute path and nothing else... But what I mean is that your "USER DIR" or "PATH" may be returning the system32 path, this way, the java or javaw may not identify which is your correct path.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Path class? It has everything that your looking for.

Comment: Can't say I've heard of it - I'll look in to it now EDIT: I'm unsure how I could use Path for an unknown file locatiom?

Comment: It is in Java 7. This class does it all, things that are related to paths.

Comment: Comments are used for clarification from OP. Not answers.