# Default FileSystem location

Tags: java, path

There is a default (FileSystem?) location in Java.

E.g. when you instantiate a `JFileChooser` without specifying what folder to open in, it will open in that default location.

I need to get that default location as a `Path` object (without use of the JFileChooser, that way just to explain).

How can I get it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get my current working directory in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153337/how-do-i-get-my-current-working-directory-in-java)

Comment: I think this question duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871051/getting-the-current-working-directory-in-java

Comment: You should be able to create a `Path` from `System.getProperty("user.dir")` which is the user's home directory

Comment: @Karlovsky120 Added with a possible example, no testing, but it should get you started

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to create a `Path` from `System.getProperty("user.home")` which is the user's home directory

Something like...

```
Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(System.getProperty("user.home"));
```

**Updated**

`JFileChooser` uses `FileSystemView` to obtain it's "default" directory

```
 Path path = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getDefaultDirectory().toPath()
```

Equally, you could also use something like...

```
Path docs = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Documents");
Path myDocs = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(System.getProperty("user.home"), "My Documents");
Path userHome = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(System.getProperty("user.home"));
```

And test each to see if they actually exist

Comment: Actually, that's not what I wanted. I expected it to open my documents, instead it opens the location of the class file...

I want it to open My documents... Users home directory, not on program scale, but whole opearting system scale...

Comment: Should be `user.home`.  You can look for "My Documents" to see if it exists, but remember, other OS's don't have a "My Documents" folder

Comment: Hmmm... I'm trying to synchronise this with the JFileChooser. If user opens a new document, a path to the document will be saved whichever it may be. However, if user creates a new document from scratch, I need to save some kind of path to the document, which would be the default JFileChooser path. How does JFileChooser get it's default source?

Comment: And that is exactly what I needed. I could manually get to My documents, but I wanted it to be platform independant. =)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for... For JFileChooser, the default directory is typically the "My Documents" folder on Windows, and the user's home directory on Unix. [Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#JFileChooser%28%29).

If you want the working directory's path, then CurrentClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath().

Comment: *"CurrentClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()"* - Wouldn't `System.getProperty("user.dir")` return the same thing?