# How do you use getDocumentBase() and getCodeBase() correctly in Java Applets?

Tags: java, applet

I am working on a project, and I'm new to applets. I don't know how to find a file using these arguments. I know there is another question out there that is almost the same, but I want this in an easy, simplified way because I'm new to this. Any help would be awesome!!! Here is my code:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class SoundDemo extends Applet
{
public void init()
{
AudioClip clip = getAudioClip( getCodeBase(), "sounds/Dragon Roost.wav" );
clip.play();
}

public void paint( Graphics g )
{
g.drawString( "Now Playing Clip", 10, 10 );
}
```

}

Comment: On what environment (OS and IDE) are you working?

Comment: Whats that mean? Sorry I'm new

Comment: Are you working on Windows system and using Eclipse IDE?

Comment: i am working on a windows system, but Eclipse IDE, what is that exactly? I think I have that

Comment: You can refer to this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153337/how-do-i-get-my-current-working-directory-in-java][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153337/how-do-i-get-my-current-working-directory-in-java

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you use getDocumentBase() and getCodeBase() in Java Applets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23817257/how-do-you-use-getdocumentbase-and-getcodebase-in-java-applets)

Comment: @Whymarrh It doesn't have any answer.

Comment: I guess it's the other way around then? They *are* the *exact* same question.

Comment: @user3666515 you have asked this question two time. just delete the other one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might help you to understand. Here I am reading a music file that is stored under `music` folder in `src` folder of my project as shown in below snapshot.

`getDocumentBase()` points to the `bin` folder (class-path) where all the classes are stored.

In your case it will fetch the music from `bin/sounds/Dragon Roost.wav`

---

#### getDocumentBase()

Gets the URL of *the document in which this applet is embedded*. For example, suppose an applet is contained within the document:

```
http://java.sun.com/products/jdk/1.2/index.html
```

The document base is:

```
http://java.sun.com/products/jdk/1.2/index.html
```

#### getCodeBase()

Gets the base URL. This is the URL of the *directory which contains this applet*.

---

Sample code:

Applet:

```
URL url = getDocumentBase();
AudioClip audioClip = getAudioClip(url, "music/JButton.wav");
```

Project structure:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

`getDocumentBase( )`

Java will allow the applet to load data from the directory holding the HTML file that started the applet (the document base)
This document base URL object is returned by the function getDocumentBase( )

`getCodeBase( )`

The directory from which the applet's class file was loaded(the code base)
This code base URL object is returned by the function getCodeBase( ).

Example code:

[image: EXAMPLE CODE]

Example output:

[image: OUTPUT]