# Java: Read image from current src directory

Tags: java, image, bufferedreader, filereader, bufferedimage

I would like to load an image from my current src directory where the java *class files* are located as well. However, I always get an **`IOException`**..

And how can I make sure the file gets loaded properly on **Mac/Linux as well on Windows**?

My code so far:

```
String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/Logo_transparent.png";
File imageFile = new File(dir);
BufferedImage bufferedImage = null;

try {
    bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    System.out.println(dir);
    System.out.println();
}
```

**IOException message:**

*Can't read input file!*

(My path is correct - is it because of the space between Google and Drive?)

*/Users/myMac/Google Drive/Privat/Programming/Logo_transparent.png*

Kind regards and thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct path?

Comment: Yes, I am! - Is there a way to test it?

Comment: Can you do `System.out.println(dir);` and tell us what it returns

Comment: Return of that is: "/Users/myMac/Google Drive/Privat/Programming"

Comment: okay can you do `System.out.println(imageFile.exists());` and see what that returns?

Comment: @Jan, the question seems to be incorrect: you're saying that you want to get this image from src directory, but referring us to `/Users/myMac/Google Drive/Privat/Programming/Logo_transparent.png`. Clarify what exactly you want to do?

Comment: `ImageIO.read` will throw this specific exception only in one case, that is when the input file is not readable (as in `!file.isReadable()`) by the Java process. Usually, this means you have to change the file access rights of your file (and/or parent folders). Could also be that the Java process is running under the wrong user.

Answer (score 0):

I think It's because you didn't create the file, You can create the file if it doesn't exist by using this code

```
if(!imageFile.exists()) imageFile.createNewFile();
```

You're code will look like this

```
String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/Logo_transparent.png";
File imageFile = new File(dir);
BufferedImage bufferedImage = null;
try {
    if(!imageFile.exists()) imageFile.createNewFile();
    bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    System.out.println(dir);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Also you shouldn't concat child files like that instead pass it as a second argument.

```
File imageFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "Logo_transparent.png");
```

Comment: It exists, I can see it in my Finder!

Comment: Can you still run the following code and see if it still shows error?

Comment: @SamzSakerz, logic is incorrect, you're checking if file exists you will re create it. You forgot negation

Comment: @SergeyProkofiev sorry, I haven't slept for 50+ hours

Comment: @SamzSakerz Why would you ever try to read an image from a newly created, empty file?

Answer (score 0):

If your image files will be packaged together with your class files (for example in the same .jar) you should not use File but read it as a resource:

```
bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Logo_transparent.png"));
```

Notice the '/' before the file name. This means to search in the root path of the classpath.
If you specify without / it will search in the package of this (the current class)

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("Logo_transparent.png")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to build the absolute path to the image like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53590888/10646754) and read it afterward.

Comment: This wasn't the question. Read the title.