# How to get IDE independend root path of a Java Project?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I have a Java project with a structure like this:

- root

  - swt.package with Main Class inside
  - data.package
  - other.package

What I need is the to get root path in my Main class.

On IntelliJ this works perfectly with `System.getProperty("user.dir")` that gives me the exact path to my `root` folder.

But on eclipse this returns  `root/swt.package`.

How can I get the same path to the root folder independend of my IDE?

Comment: You can use `user.dir`, but you have to configure the Run Configuration in Eclipse to start the program in that directory.

Comment: it is kind of *strange*  to need the root path of your project, unless developing some plugin for the IDE (which would conflict with being IDE-independent) - what is expected after deployment? (`user.dir` will retrieve the current working directory when the application was started)

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153337/how-to-get-current-working-directory-in-java/3153413#3153413